# Can I use 2 routers for 2 separate networks in my house, both plugged into the wall?

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, connection, modem

I have a Belkin router and I am thinking of buying something like a tp link wr841n and a td-8616 with.

Without the Belkin would work to create a connection for me, however I have a garage about 10m away from my house and I want to be able to use my laptop in it.

I don't mind having to log in to different networks I would prefer to have to, but will it work if I plug my Belkin trough some a adapters in two the phone line or do I have to plug the Belkin in the the back of the tp link and do a load of wiring so long that the properly wouldn't be any internet reaching the other end?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to extend your network and your Belkin supports WDS, you only need the wr841n (as it supports WDS, too). The [instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/182631/how-to-create-wds-wireless-link-between-two-home-wireless-routers) (#1) may differ from model to model but the concept is the same. Also take a look [here](http://www.tp-link.com/us/article/?id=227). To form "differnt networks" example:

```
Belkin:                        wr841n:
IP:     192.168.1.1            IP:     192.168.1.2
Subnet: 255.255.255.0          Subnet: 255.255.255.0
DHCP server: ON                DHCP server: ON
DHCP Pool:                     DHCP Pool:
192.168.1.50 - 100             192.168.1.150 - 200
```

There is no need for a wire to connect the two routers. The new router will use 192.168.1.2, while the Belkin will us e192.168.1.1. The Belkin will assign IP addresses 192.168.1.50 to ...100 to clients within its range. The wr841n can also provide IP addresses to clients as long as the range of IP addresses does not conflict with the first one, thus the example.

You only need the td-8616 if you want a different connection (e.g. different ISP, or split connection, etc.), or replace your old modem (if you are currently using a separate one for the Belkin).

Comment: thanks could you but a am still not sure i can plug the routers in to to seperate adsl/phone line jack in the wall and create to seperate networks from the seperat modemes or will it be the same network

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop has wifi card, you might want to look into Repeaters that extends you wireless signal.